# C++ Pseudo Destructor on Array Type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, stl

I'm using `std::aligned_storage` and need to store array types in the `aligned_storage`. The following code compiles in visual cpp but not Clang.

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type store;

    template <typename... Args>
    Foo(Args&&... args)
    {
        new (&store) T { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    }

    void Release()
    {
        reinterpret_cast<T*>(&store)->~T(); // Clang problems here
    }
};

Foo<int> a(2); // ok
Foo<int[3]> b(1, 2, 3); // error in clang
```

The specific error is:

```
 expression of non-scalar type 'T' (aka 'int [3]') cannot be used in a pseudo-destructor expression
```

Is this valid C++ and how should I properly destruct array types manually?

Comment: Specialize your template for array types?

Comment: Tip: `union{T v;} store;` also defines a suitable for storing a `T`, without calling any pesky ctors.

Comment: @Deduplicator This example was greatly simplified and there are good reasons to prefer aligned_storage over unions in c++.

Comment: @MattBierner: Name one good reason to prefer `std::aligned_storage` over a `union` in that case please. (It feels like you reduced the test-case much, sure.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The program is ill-formed, you may not use a pseudo destructor call on an array type. §5.2.4 Pseudo destructor call [expr.pseudo]:

> 1. The use of a *pseudo-destructor-name* after a dot `.` or arrow `->` operator represents the destructor for the non-class type denoted by *type-name* or *decltype-specifier*. ...
> 2. The left-hand side of the dot operator shall be of scalar type. The left-hand side of the arrow operator shall be of pointer to scalar type. ...

An overloaded function can handle the destruction appropriately for both array and non-array types by manually destroying each of the array elements ([Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/352f491ff4374780)):

```
template <typename T>
void destroy(T& t)
{
    t.~T();
}

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
void destroy(T (&t)[N])
{
    for (auto i = N; i-- > 0;) {
        destroy(t[i]);
    }
}

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type store;

    template <typename... Args>
    Foo(Args&&... args)
    {
        new (&store) T { std::forward<Args>(args)... };
    }

    void Release()
    {
        destroy(reinterpret_cast<T&>(store));
    }
};
```

Comment: Looks good. Was the original code invalid or was Clang wrong?

Comment: @MattBierner Code was ill-formed. I've put a short explanation in the answer.

Comment: It seems like there ought to be a standard library solution for this problem. Is there nothing akin to `std::destroy<T>()` already provided in C++11 or C++14?

Comment: I'm greatly confused. Does std::vector have an overload for arrays to handle this?