# TBB: Can't use an array type?

Tags: c++, templates, tbb

I have some code that uses TBB:

```
tbb::concurrent_vector<float[3]> vnors2;
vnors2.resize(NUM_VERTS);

tbb::concurrent_vector<float[3]> lnors_weighted2;
lnors_weighted2.resize(NUM_LOOPS);
```

and I get an error compiling this (Windows, Visual Studio 2019):

```
non-scalar type 'T' cannot be used in a pseudo-destructor expression
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26307698/c-pseudo-destructor-on-array-type) it looks like I need to re-write the class, but this isn't mine. Is there any way to address this? I could re-write my code to use a struct, but I'd prefer to use the array.

Comment: No idea what TBB is, but I guess `tbb::concurrent_vector<std::array<float, 3>>` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, @Yksisarvinen you are correct. The issue is indeed not related to TBB. @easythrees You can find more about the syntax of array in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array